# Thinnig of a binary image: python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was trying to skeletonize an image. Using this code, to an extent the image came out as I wanted. But still there are some issues in the image. I can find some gaps in between the lines. Is there any better alogorithm to get rid of those gaps.I have attached the input and the output of the given code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("e_5.jpg",0)
size = np.size(img)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
img = 255 - img
img = cv2.dilate(img, element, iterations=3)

done = False

while( not done):
   eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
   temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
   temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
   skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
   img = eroded.copy()

   zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
   if zeros==size:
    done = True
```

[image: original image]
[image: binary]
[image: dilate]
[image: skeletonized image]

Comment: You have some indentation issues in your code, especially your `if zeros==size` should be inside your while loop.

Comment: Can you show the images of the intermediate steps too? That way we can analyze exactly which step needs some different parameters or so

Comment: the code is updated. it was a mistake when i pasted here.

Comment: @usethedeathstar I have added the intermediate images also. 1) input image 2) binary image 3) dilated image 4) skeletonized image

Comment: Your code for skeletonizing is correct. It's probably the nature of your shapes which is why there is a gap.  You may want to adjust the thresholds or perhaps change the structuring element that produces the binary image before skeletonization and see if that has an effect on the output.

Comment: I think you continue the process too long maybe, or that your element is too large? I guess the point is that you dont want your tree to be with a branch thats loose on the right?

Comment: Just for reference: I think, this is the algorithm from here: http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/